# how to display directory name

Tags: currfile

I'm trying to use the `\currfiledir` command on my homework template, so I can change even less of my header every time I start a new document, see mwe:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}
\author{Brent DeJong}
\title{\currfiledir~\\ Homework ***}
\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\runtitle}
\rhead{\runauthor\\ Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\begin{document}
\getmainfile
\begin{flushright}  
\runauthor \\
\runtitle \\
\today \\
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the `\currfiledir` command returns nothing.

I'm running TeXWorks via a MiXTeX distribution on Windows 8.1, so I don't know how to implement a commandline-based solution for this on my system. I get only the file name if I use `\currfilepath` or `\currfilename`. Is this package viable on Windows? How do I take advantage of it?

Comment: `\currfiledir` expands to nothing for the main file, because there is *no* complete path available, just the file name. This is confirmed by the fact that `\currfilepath` just shows the file name.

Comment: @egreg Is there a way I can get a complete path to be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here works fine for me on miktex and shows the absolute path if I compile twice with `pdflatex --recorder`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\begin{document}
dir: \currfileabsdir
\end{document}
```