# Only name appears when using currfile

Tags: xetex, currfile

My problem was partly addressed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228924/how-to-display-directory-name). Since I cannot comment yet, I will continue [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228928/106417) with a new question.

The expample worked on my system as well with pdflatex, but it fails when I use xelatex. Furthermore, even pdflatex only works with absolute directory, not with the other commands from the currfile package.

I extended the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\begin{document}
abs dir: \currfileabsdir

dir: \currfiledir

base: \currfilebase

ext: \currfileext

name: \currfilename

path: \currfilepath


jobname: \jobname


\end{document}
```

The result with xelatex looks like this:

[image: Result with Xelatex]

When I use pdflatex, I get almost the same result, only the absolute directory works fine.

Any suggestions?

My setup: TexLive 2015; Mac OS 10.11

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to run the engine with the `-recorder` option in order for `currfile` to find the required data.

Comment: Now I got a pdf with the command `xelatex --recorder test.tex` and the absolute path is printed. The other paths (dir, path) are not yet printed. -- But I can live with it. Now I am searching for a way to enter the --recorder option into a GUI like TeXShop -- still searching, will come back.