# Retrieving name, path and directory information of currently loaded file with \currfile

Tags: expl3

1. I understand that package `currfile` provides information on the currently loaded file like name, path, directory, etc. `\currfilename` and `\currfileext` deliver as promised, `\currfiledir`  and `\currfilepath` return blanks. Why?
2. I am told that the `expl3` core now provides its own access to current filename and path. Is this as documented in `ltfilehook`, dated 17 June 2021? Since `\CurrentFile` and
   `\CurrentFilePath` compile with `\usepackage{currfile}` commented out, I take it my system is up to date. However, keeping with the tradition, both `\CurrentFile` and `\CurrentFilePath` return blanks.

Anyone interested in providing some clues?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 24 June 2021
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{currfile}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\verb+\c_sys_jobname_str+ = \c_sys_jobname_str 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\verb+\currfilename+ = \currfilename

\verb+\currfileext+ = \currfileext

\verb+\currfiledir+ = \currfiledir

\verb+\currfilepath+ = \currfilepath

\verb+\CurrentFilePath+ = \CurrentFilePath

\verb+\CurrentFile+ = \CurrentFile

\end{document}
```

Comment: regarding currfile, you want the absdir https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228928/2388

Comment: `\CurrentFile` is only useful if you use file hooks, then it contains the current file name.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I am using `\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}` and `\currfileabsdir` as per your previous post, but still get blanks.

Comment: did you read my complete answer? Including the first sentence?

Comment: The paths return empty because TeX doesn't care where in your system you are running your document. `\CurrentFile` (which is a LaTeX command, you don't need to load `expl3`) returns empty in the main `.tex` file because we (as in I) didn't initialise it... Maybe we should...

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Would be great if you would. My requirement may seem a little far-fetched, but I work from a set of template `.tex` files, in which I have to manually set the path to the directory where my projects reside. Having the system supply me with that path my templates would be automated. Not a big thing, but relocating projects currently is a pain.